# JQuery Saving data to Cookies (Mobile Widget)

Tags: jquery, cookies, mobile

I'm attempting to save strings inputed by users using JQuery Cookies. I've trawled through google but to no avail, i'd like to make the data i send to cookies structured as there will be many different places users will have to add text to (XML?).
Cheers,
Kay

Answer (score 0):

I am recommending [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) and if you need more read about [subcookies](http://blog.valugi.ro/2009/09/13/subcookies-in-jquery/).

Comment: I'm experimenting with the jQuery cookie plugin, but the demonstation + examples online aren't very clear/helpful. Subcookies are designed for for YUI i think.